# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: machine-learning, symbols

The X in a circle. It's from a Learning Theory paper.

I've seen that to mean XOR but I don't see how that could be right in this case.

[image: circled X symbol]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensor product. See the wiki page for more info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: OK, the post has been edited, I misread it :)